# How to add the items to start from the second cell and not in the column header cell?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void DisplayTableWithListview()
        {
            listView1.GridLines = true;// Whether the grid lines are displayed
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;// Whether to select the entire line

            listView1.View = View.Details;// Set display mode
            listView1.Scrollable = true;// Whether to show the scroll bar automatically
            listView1.MultiSelect = false;// Is it possible to select multiple lines

            // Add header(column)
            listView1.Columns.Add("ToString(yyyyMMddHHmm)", 160, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
            
            // Add items into table
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.SubItems.Clear();

                item.SubItems[0].Text = "Product" + i.ToString();
                item.SubItems.Add(i.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add((i + 7).ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add((i * i).ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Product0 is in the cell/place of the column header.
i want the items to be start added from the second cell.

[image: table]

Comment: I think you can simply do `item.SubItems[0].Text = "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `listView1.Items.Insert(index , item)` to add item in specialty index. [listview.listviewitemcollection.insert()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.insert?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

```
listView1.Items.Insert(2,"yourItem");
```

if you want the items to be start added from the second cell try this:

```
        listView1.Items.Add("");
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.SubItems.Clear();

            item.SubItems[0].Text = "Product" + i.ToString();
            item.SubItems.Add(i.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add((i + 7).ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add((i * i).ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

[image]